# WinJS ListView Dynamic Grouping

Tags: listview, grouping, winjs

I have a pretty standard WinJS ListView setup to bind to some grouped data.

Based on an app settings, I want to change whether the grouping is shown or not shown. I can partially do that by checking when the page loads and skipping setting grouping properties like so:

```
            if (!Data.getCategoryGrouping()) {
                var content = element.querySelector(".itemspage");
                content.className += " noGroup";
                listView.groupHeaderTemplate = null;
                listView.groupDataSource = null;
            }
            else {
                listView.groupHeaderTemplate = element.querySelector(".headerTemplate");
                listView.groupDataSource = Data.groups.dataSource;
            }
```

However, that doesn't help in the case where the page is already visible and the user adjusts the settings. (And honestly probably isn't the best way to go about it anyway.)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

After the page has been loaded, you can just null out the groupDataSource to turn off the grouping. Like this...

```
q("#myButton").onclick = function(e) {
    myListView.groupDataSource = null;
};
```

And you can just toggle it with that button like this...

```
q("#myButton").onclick = function(e) {
    if (myListView.groupDataSource != null) myListView.groupDataSource = null;
    else { myListView.groupDataSource = myGroupedList.groups.dataSource; }
};
```

BTW, instead of using `content.className += " noGroup";` as you were doing in your code, I recommend you use `content.classList.add("noGroup");`.

Comment: Thanks Jack - I made the classList change. :-) With the groupDataSource, I'm doing a very similar thing. My problem seems to be getting it to apply that change while the page is already displayed, and then having the listview respond properly to that change.

Comment: That's strange. I ran through a little test and when I do it you see the ListView refresh with the changes (grouping and then no grouping). I'm not wiring any ListView events to make it refresh. It happens on its own.